# GCP service account key - JSON validation

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform describes the service account key in [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#creating) and gives an example JSON as

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "PROJECT_ID",
  "private_key_id": "KEY_ID",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
  "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
}
```

Is there a JSON schema for validating a GCP service account key, or a Google cloud client library providing a method for key validation? Thank you!

Comment: I have not seen a schema published, but I am certain Google has one internally. Is your goal to validate that the JSON contents are valid or just the keys? If your goal is to verify that the contents are valid, extract the public key from the private key and verify with `client_x509_cert_url`. The only method I know to verify that the material is still valid is by creating an assertion and exchanging it for an OAuth token. You only need two keys `private_key` and `client_email` plus optionally `private_key_id`. The rest are informational keys.

Comment: In addition to @JohnHanley comment, I would like to ask WHY do you need to validate the schema? Did you investigate other solutions to avoid the service account key file usage? JSON keys are bad practices and create potential security breaches.

Comment: Thank you, JohnHanley, for the suggestions.
Regarding your question, @GuillaumeBlaquiere, it is for a custom tool where end users can upload the key file. Therefore the usage of the key file cannot be avoided in this case.

Comment: It depends on the type of tool! And where it runs and so on. If it runs locally, you can use the user credential, and the service account email to impersonate it. If the tool runs on Google Cloud, you can use the metadata server to get the credential (and optionally also perform impersonation). Of course, if the tools run on prem and in automated way (no connected user when the tool is used), yes service account keys are required.